# ReactJS client fails to communicate with Java web service

Tags: java, reactjs, web-services

I have written a web service in Java. And a client in ReactJS that calls my web service and displays the response. I run my client at localhost:8081 and my web service on Tomcat Apache at localhost:8080. But I am getting an error (posted below) when I run my client. Please tell what can be the issue in my code?

**Error:**
[image]

**View.jsx *(client)*:**

```
import React from 'react';

class View extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            text: "initial state"
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "localhost:8080/UserManagement/rest/myService/data"
        }).then((function(data) {
            this.setState({text: data});
        }).bind(this))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.text}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default View;
```

**MyServer.java *(web service)*:**

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.json.JSONObject;


@Path("myService")
public class MyServer {

    @GET
    @Path("/data")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

    public Response queryRESTService(InputStream incomingData) {

        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            String output = "";
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\myJSON.txt");
            InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                output += line + "\n";
            }
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(output);
            bufferedReader.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return Response.status(200).entity(jsonObject.toString()).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/verify")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response verifyRESTService() {
        String result = "MyRESTService Successfully started..";
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
    }

}
```

Comment: https://enable-cors.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are not much aware of CORS which stands for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. According to web standards, it is not allowed. So what you have to do is set a CORS header in Java to allow the client-side to make a request. This will help: [Using CORS headers with Java](https://amodernstory.com/2014/12/27/using-cors-headers-with-java-example/)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify any protocol in the url.

In your view.jsx file, change the url to "http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/rest/myService/data".